# "Language support" icon missing in System Settings

Tags: 13.04, language-support, system-settings

The "Language Support" icon from the System settings has disappeared:

[image: No language support icon in System Settings]

(Also I can't find it from Dash)

The last thing I've done was changing the keyboard input method system to "ibus".

I tried to execute `gnome-control-center` directly in the command line, expecting to see errors in the output, but there is no console output.

Where can I start looking for the cause? Can I call the "Language Support" option directly from command line?

Comment: Reinstalling `gnome-control-center` usually helps.

Comment: Try running the command `gnome-language-selector`.
If that doesn't work, make sure you have the package `language-selector-gnome` installed.

Comment: @DoR I had to install that package, after that the "Language Support" icon appears again! I think the cause was the `im-switch` package. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *Language Support* utility is provided by the language-selector-gnome package

`sudo apt-get install language-selector-gnome`

Once you install that package, you'll see the language option in the *System Settings* again.

Comment: Language Support did not appear for me, but I was able to run gnome-language-selector from the terminal instead.

Comment: I can confirm that in 18.04, the installation of `gnome-control-center` and `language-selector-gnome` is not enough to force the "Region & Language" tab to appear in the `gnome-control-center`. Here's my particulars: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7Fnz75s9qc/