# how to install language-selector-gnome correctly in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, package-management, language-support

On my laptop I can't find the language support icon in system setting.

I use the solution from [the accepted answer in Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331515/language-support-icon-missing-in-system-settings/331872#331872)
I get the error

```
language-selector-gnome: Depends: language-selector-common (= 0.129) `
```

So I try to install `language-selector-gnome` in terminal with

```
apt-get install language-selector-gnome
```

I get the error

```
language-selector-gnome : Dependencies: language-selector-common (= 0.129)
```

So I try to install `language-selector-common` in terminal

```
apt-get install language-selector-common
```

It works fine, no error

And I return back to `apt-get install language-selector-gnome`,the previous error comes back again.

I don't know if I install the dependencies correctly, and how I can install `language-selector-gnome` to get the language support icon back.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32bit system

And the output of the command `dpkg-query -W language-selector-common`

is
`language-selector-common   0.129.3`

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the output of `dpkg-query -W language-selector-common`

Answer (score 1):

Version 0.129.3 is the current version in trusty-updates, while 0.129 is the version in trusty-release. This makes me believe that you previously had trusty-updates enabled, but have disabled it for some reason.

So to fix it, open *Software & Updates*, select the *Updates* tab, and enable trusty-updates. Then close the window and click the *Reload* button. After that you should be able to install language-selector-gnome 0.129.3.